# Determining the source of Illegal instruction error

Tags: gdb

Building Thunderbird / Firefox with LLVM 3.4 or newer on i386 results in a crash during the install phase; this problem does not happen with amd64. The issue has shown up both with a VM running under VMware and on bare metal but I have also been able to run on other bare metal i386 systems without issue. My guess is this could be a code generation issue with LLVM and from what I have heard mentioned elsewhere this started somewhere between LLVM 3.3 and 3.4 but I don't know if this is really an LLVM issue or an issue with the relevant code within the installer for Thunderbird / Firefox.

```
gmake[1]: Entering directory '/usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mail/installer'
OMNIJAR_NAME=omni.ja \
/usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/_virtualenv/bin/python /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/toolkit/mozapps/installer/packager.py -DMOZ_GLUE_IN_PROGRAM -DMOZ_THUNDERBIRD=1 -DOSTYPE=\"OpenBSD5\" -DOSARCH=OpenBSD -DNO_NSPR_10_SUPPORT -DAB_CD=en-US -DMOZ_APP_NAME=thunderbird -DPREF_DIR=defaults/pref -DMOZ_ENABLE_GNOME_COMPONENT=1 -DMOZ_GTK2=1 -DJAREXT= -DMOZ_NATIVE_NSPR=1 -DMOZ_NATIVE_NSS=1 -DMOZ_CHILD_PROCESS_NAME=plugin-container -DDLL_PREFIX=lib -DDLL_SUFFIX=.so.28.0 -DBIN_SUFFIX= -DBINPATH=bin \
        --format omni \
        --removals /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mail/installer/removed-files.in \
     \
     \
     \
    --optimizejars \
     \
    package-manifest ../../mozilla/dist ../../mozilla/dist/thunderbird \
    --non-resource defaults/messenger/mailViews.dat
Executing /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/xpcshell -g /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/ -a /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/ -f /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/toolkit/mozapps/installer/precompile_cache.js -e precompile_startupcache("resource://gre/");
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/toolkit/mozapps/installer/packager.py", line 375, in <module>
main()
  File "/usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/toolkit/mozapps/installer/packager.py", line 367, in main
args.source, gre_path, base)
  File "/usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/toolkit/mozapps/installer/packager.py", line 148, in precompile_cache
    errors.fatal('Error while running startup cache precompilation')
  File "/usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/python/mozbuild/mozpack/errors.py", line 101, in fatal
self._handle(self.FATAL, msg)
  File "/usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/python/mozbuild/mozpack/errors.py", line 96, in _handle
raise ErrorMessage(msg)
mozpack.errors.ErrorMessage: Error: Error while running startup cache precompilation
```

I am looking for some assistance with the relevant tools to try and determine the source of this Illegal instruction error.

```
Core was generated by `xpcshell'.
Program terminated with signal 4, Illegal instruction.
```

I used the core file instead of running gdb as you specified..

```
# egdb build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/xpcshell build-i386/mail/installer/xpcshell.core
Python Exception <type 'exceptions.ImportError'> No module named gdb: 

warning: 
Could not load the Python gdb module from `/usr/local/share/gdb/python'.
Limited Python support is available from the _gdb module.
Suggest passing --data-directory=/path/to/gdb/data-directory.

GNU gdb (GDB) 7.6.1
Copyright (C) 2013 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i386-unknown-openbsd5.5".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/xpcshell...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
[New process 13685]
Core was generated by `xpcshell'.
Program terminated with signal 4, Illegal instruction.
#0  0x002ead4d in mozilla::BinaryPath::GetFile(char const*, nsIFile**) () from /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/libxul.so.28.0
(gdb) x/i $pc
=> 0x2ead4d <_ZN7mozilla10BinaryPath7GetFileEPKcPP7nsIFile+157>:        ud2    
(gdb) quit
# echo _ZN7mozilla10BinaryPath7GetFileEPKcPP7nsIFile+157 | c++filt
mozilla::BinaryPath::GetFile(char const*, nsIFile**)+157
```

Answer (score 0):

> looking for some assistance with the relevant tools to try and determine the source of this Illegal instruction error

Your first task is to understand *what* illegal instruction you are trying to execute.

Run `xpcshell` under GDB like so:

```
gdb --args /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/xpcshell \
  -g /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/ -a \
  /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/build-i386/mozilla/dist/bin/ -f \
  /usr/ports/pobj/thunderbird-24.2.0/comm-esr24/mozilla/toolkit/mozapps/installer/precompile_cache.js -e \
  precompile_startupcache("resource://gre/");

(gdb) run
... GDB will stop on SIGILL
(gdb) x/i $pc
```

Once you know what the illegal instruction is, you'll need to figure out why Clang produced it.

One likely possibility is the `ud2` instruction, which Clang emits when it detects [undefined behavior](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) in the program.

Comment: Thank you for the response. This will help me move in the right direction.